# How to display image file with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I have successfully managed to save the filename to my mongodb database, but I can't seem to figure out how to display the image to handlebars page. This is the code that I'm using:

```
router.get('/showPost/:id',(req,res) => {
Post.findById(req.params.id).then((post) => {
   res.render('showPost',{ post: post})
        
    });
```

This is how I try to display my image, but it only appears as a broken icon.

```
<img src = {{{post.image}}} >
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(post)`?

Comment: This is what I get when I try to display the image : Cast to ObjectId failed for value "image_1.jpg" at path "_id" for model "Post".

Comment: Sounds like `req.params.id` is not suitable as a mongoDB ObjectId. Is `req.params.id` empty or not a 12-byte string? `console.log('req.params.id')` what you get?

Comment: I have changed my code to this: <img src = "/uploads/{{post.image}} > and still the image appears as a broken icon but now the error message is this: Cannot GET /uploads/image_1.jpg. uploads folder is located at the root of my project.

Comment: Please provide the whole router file.

Comment: Update! I managed to solve the issue. I had to use this code: <img src = " /{{post.image}}" >. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you setup your index.js properly?

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Create root folder call public. Put your images there

Then do

```
 <img src="/{{post.image}}>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to solve the problem with the same approach as you suggested.